# NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS Error

Tags: apex, custom-button, error, exception, button

Hello all I've created a custom button using code. The idea is the user clicks, on the button and it sends an approval request.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/apex.js")} 
sforce.apex.execute("CreateNewApproval","SendApprovalRequest", {id:"
{!Account.Id}"}); 
window.alert("Record sent for approval" );
```

Here is the assocaited Apex code I am using:

```
global class CreateNewApproval {

WebService static void SendApprovalRequest(String id) {
// create the new approval request to submit
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
req.setObjectId(id);
// submit the approval request for processing
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req);
// display if the reqeust was successful
System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());

}
}
```

Every time I attempt to execute the code, I get an error saying NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS and I am unsure how to fix it. Attached is a screen shot of the full error code.

[image]

Any solutions this problem?

Edit: Pictures of two approval processes
[image]

Comment: We can't possibly answer the question without knowing all of your approval process criteria and all the corresponding data about the record. The error itself is pretty descriptive. Your record doesn't fit any entry criteria. It's a data problem, not a code problem.

Comment: adding pics of my approval processes right now

Comment: did my answer solved your issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error that you get when you try to submit a record that doesn't match the entry criteria for any of your Approval Processes on the given object (`Account`, in this case), or if you don't have any "active" approval processes for the given object.

Unfortunately, there isn't really a good way right now to programatically determine whether or not a given record meets the entry criteria for at least one approval proceess without trying to submit it and handling any errors that pop up.

Your choices here are to:

- Adjust the entry criteria to be more permissive (up to making the entry criteria a formula that simply returns `true`, to allow all records to enter that process)
- Duplicate the entry criteria in your javascript, and do a pre-check of entry criteria before making your remoting call (so you can provide a better error message, telling users what needs to change)
- Use workflow, validation, process builder, triggers (or a combination thereof) to ensure that your records always meet the entry criteria

Comment: So I don't have any criteria for the approval processes, do you suggest I add a very simple one just to allow the approval process to start?

Otherwise, i think I may need to modify the >account

Comment: @Matt hmm, if you don't have entry criteria, it shouldn't be a problem. It would be helpful if you would [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/180792/edit) to include a screenshot of the approval processes on the `Account` object as well as a screenshot of the detail page for the approval process you're trying to send your record into.

Comment: sure thing, just adding them now.

So I have two approval processes (which maybe is the problem?) but neither have entry criteria. I cannot add a picture of the second on due my low rep number... The object name is "application" but replacing that for account, makes the syntax for the button incorrect....

Comment: @Matt If an object has more than one active approval process, I believe that Salesforce starts at the top of the process order list (starts at 1, then checks 2, then 3, etc...) until it finds the first one that can accept the given record (based on entry criteria). If Salesforce reaches the final approval process, and the record can't enter it, you get the `NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS` error.

Comment: @Matt That said, I think Santanu Boral has hit the nail on the head now. The approval processes you've included are defined for the `Contact` object, and your javascript indicates that you're trying to submit an `Account` for approval. Since `Account` != `Contact`, Salesforce isn't considering your `Contact` approval processes when you submit an `Account` for approval. Do you have any approval processes defined on the `Account` object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Approval Process on that `Account` Object and that must be **activated**.

Since, from your code, it is evident that either you haven't defined the approval process or that is not active.

Make a note that the recordId you will pass this method, approval process must be defined on that object.

```
req.setObjectId(id);
```

It seems you are passing `Account.Id` in this method, but you have defined approval process on Contact (as Initial Submitter is `Contact Owner`).

That's why system is unable to find approval processes.

Comment: So which part of my code would I need to change to define the approval process?

Comment: On which object you have defined the approval process? Account or Contact? It seems you have defined on contact

Comment: check my answer....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a formal answer, just adding a picture of my second approval process for people to use to help answer (since my acc is new I cannot post more than 2 links)
[image]